# Heading text is blocking floated elements

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

Please have a look:

http://jsfiddle.net/JeaffreyGilbert/b8FdC/

How to place button above the line in IE7? Please don't change the HTML structure. Thanks.

Comment: Im almost 100% certain that your html is invalid... dont think elements should appear within an h2 tag...

Comment: without changing structure...?? u need to change only order see the answer

Comment: @Damien You can place inline elements within a `h2`.

Comment: @alex there you go, i stand corrected... still looks funny to me :P

Comment: @Damien Yeah, I wouldn't put a `button` in a `h2` myself :P

Comment: Ok, will wrap the h2 and other element(s) with a div. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do the simple **hack** , change the order. write `<button`> before the text and also write `float:left` on `h2`

```
<h2>
 <button>Action button</button>
 This is heading 2   
</h2>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xkeshav/b8FdC/1/)

**Note:** also can work only writing `float:left` on `h2` but then complete div slip below

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you'll have to change the structure by putting the the button element to before the "this is heading 2" text. (EDIT: diEcho beat me to it).
Otherwise you'll have to use `position:absolute` which can cause other problems. Using `position:relative` on the h2 may help.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/nm8yt/)